# replace text between two white-spaces in R

Tags: r, replace

I have this string:

```
  \tBangkok\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t.
```

In this string I want replace the text between "\t" and "\t" (i.e. Bangkok) with Hanoi. 
So the result will be

```
   \tHanoi\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t
```

Moreover, I want replace the text between "1\t" and "\t" with a text like

```
   "AFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT"
```

(with the same lenght).

```
   \tHanoi\t 1\tAFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT\t
```

I should do the same for several lines so I would like to find a more general command for doing it.

Comment: Try `sub('\\w+', 'Hanoi', str1)`

Comment: I tried but gave me just the word Hanoi.

Comment: It was for the first case. `str1 <- "\tBangkok\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t"; sub('\\w+', 'Hanoi', str1)
#[1] "\tHanoi\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t."`   Anyway, I didn't try for the other case as you already got a solution below.

Comment: You could also use the [stringi package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html): `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("\tBangkok\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t", c("\t.*?\t", "(\\d+)\t.*?\t"), c("\tHanoi\t", "$1\tAFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT\t"), vectorize_all = FALSE)`.

Comment: If you have multiple text to replace, may be `v1 <-  c("Hanoi", "AFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT"); sapply(strsplit(str1, '\t'), function(x) {x[grep('^[A-Za-z]+$', x)] <- v1; paste(x, collapse='\t')})#
[1] "\tHanoi\t 1\tAFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT\t."` would be an option

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
> x <- "\tBangkok\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t"
> gsub("\\B\\t\\K\\w+(?=\\t)", "HAnoi", x, perl=T)
[1] "\tHAnoi\t 1\tAGGGGCCHCCTTTTCTCTTTCTCT\t"
> y <- gsub("\\B\\t\\K\\w+(?=\\t)", "HAnoi", x, perl=T)
> gsub("(1\\t)\\w+(\\t)", "\\1AFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT\\2", y, perl=T)
[1] "\tHAnoi\t 1\tAFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT\t"
```

Comment: Yes, with this command I obtain what I wanted but the problem is that in the second command I had to use \\1 and \\2 in the text to add. Is there not a command that take just "AFGGGKKKKCTTJJCTCTTTCTCT" and put it between \t and \t?